# How to add a channel in MS Teams using PowerShell (Non-Interactive)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to add a channel to a team via a non-interactive PowerShell script. I have Connect-MgGraph working and I'm able to query our AD (application registered, cert working, permissions set, etc.). I think I need to use Connect-MicrosoftTeams possibly passing my application credential, but I can't find a way to get the applications access token to pass.  I followed the directions for the -AccessTokens parameter in the documentation to configure the "AAD application". (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps)

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks- Paul.

Comment: With OIDC/OAuth2, non-interactive clients don't store access-tokens directly, instead they store `client_credentials` and use that to authenticate, and if successful then the client then gets a short-lived access-token (which expires typically after 5 to 60 minutes). An OAuth2 `access_token` should never be saved anywhere - it should only ever exist in transient memory and be kept as secret as possible (because, _generally speaking_, `access_token`s cannot be revoked, hence their relatively short lifetime)

Comment: Hi @P-Time Does the above mentioned solution works for you ?